# PHP — Information on the zip:// protocol

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using `ZipArchive` class to unzip a file and put its contents somewhere useful. Using information derived from the comments on `php.net`, I ended up writing this function:

```
function unzip(string $zipFile, string $destination) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zipFile);
    for($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++) {
         $file=$zip->getNameIndex($i);
         if(substr($file,-1) == '/') continue;  //  skip containing folder
         $name=basename($file);
         copy("zip://$zipFile#$file","$destination/$name");
     }
    $zip->close();      
}
```

This is to copy the individual files without the folder structure.

I can understand most of the code, but I cannot get any information on the following expression:

```
"zip://$zipFile#$file"
```

I know what it doing (obviously it is extracting one of the files from the Zip archive), but can anyone tell me more about the `zip://` protocol, and why it uses the `#` to reference a particular file?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check out source of **Zip** extension
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/zip/zip_stream.c

line 135. `fragment = strchr(path, '#');`

*get pointer of entry in path/to/zip#entry*

line 141.

```
if (strncasecmp("zip://", path, 6) == 0)
{
   path += 6;
}
```

*if `zip://` is equal first 6 characters of `path`*

I won't go into the logic of this code. It just exists here (zip_stream.c) and maybe somewhere else.

It seems like this extension "creates" `zip://` protocol over php executable that is laying over apache server.